# GPL/LGPL: Is it sufficient to only put the Corresponding Source's download link in the binary distribution?

Tags: gpl, lgpl

[GPLv3](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.en.html) clause 6d states the following (emphasis mine):

> Convey the object code by offering access from a designated place (gratis or for a charge), and offer equivalent access to the Corresponding Source **in the same way through the same place** at no further charge.

I'm wondering what exactly "same place" entails here.

Let's suppose I'm hosting a website to distribute an LGPL-licensed dll file packaged with my non-LGPL application binary. Is it sufficient for me to include the download link for the proper version of the dll's source code in a README as part of my binary application distribution? Or do I need to have a download link for the proper version of the dll's source code on the same webpage that hosts the download for my binary distribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but:

It is sufficient to offer the download only to your customers or the people who receive the binary from you. If the people do not receive the corresponding source code with the identical download (thus one file), you have to make sure to offer a solution these customers can obtain the source code *for the exact version they got* even in the future. The time span to consider at least usually is three years after the last distribution of the binary built from it.

The same place could be for instance your website or another location *you control*, link mentioned in the README you ship. On the website you offer the source downloads for each version you distribute(d). You should not rely on a 3rd-party ressource to remain active and available.

If you force your customers to get the complete corresponding source code along with your binary *with each download* (thus bundling them in a single zip file for both), you probably are good. However, this then would have to be the case for each patch and update you distribute as well; your customers might not appreciate the additional unwanted download each time, and you might not want the additional traffic.

Comment: I am not really sure what your "Yes" refers to.

Comment: To the question the title poses.